# How to use RedirectToRoute("routeName") in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoroute

I am just puzzled on why is my RedirectToRoute() method not working. I have a RouteConfig.cs file like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "pattern1",
    "{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "About" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "pattern2",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

on this configuration my default controller **Home** and action **About** is getting called, now in the action method I am calling RedirectToRoute() with the following value like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult About()
{
    return RedirectToRoute("pattern2");
}
```

Why is the RedirectToRoute() not calling Admin/Index action

Answer (score 6):

This is because of the route you have defined. RedirectToRoute() redirects to the route you have defined. The url you have defined for "pattern2" is "{controller}/{action}/{id}". If you want to use the overload which only accepts the routeName, then you need explicitly define the url in your RouteConfig. Example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "pattern2",
    "Admin/Index",
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If you do not want to define the url explicitly, then you need to use a different overload of RedirectToRoute() which accepts the routeValues object.

Comment: why is it not taking me to the default controller and action which i have mentioned the MapRoute method()? if i have to define Admin/Index, then it would be a static value, then what is the purpose of RedirectToRoute(), i could have used redirecToAction instead. I want to know the exact user of this method so that i could take advantage of it.. thank you

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
return RedirectToRoute(new 
{ 
    controller = "Admin", 
    action = "Index", 
    id = null 
});
```

You could also use RedirectToAction() method. It seems more intuitive.

Comment: yeah, i know how to use this overload, however i am trying to learn to use the overload which states to name the route. How to use that ie, RedirectToRoute(string RouteName)